# STM32F303K8 ADC value is between 27 to 112 instead of 4095

Tags: stm32

I have an STM32F303K8 and I am reading now ADC values. The values are too small. Between 27 and 112 instead of going up to 4095. Any idea why?

Can it be because I am debugging with USB port and `STM32` is only connected to USB. Will it have enough power?

[image]

I am talking about Pin7 or Pa4

[image]

Code

```
static returnCode_t remoteInputs_getADCbufferAverage(uint16_t* buffer, uint32_t size, uint16_t *AverageADC)
{
    if( (buffer != first_half) && (buffer != second_half) )
    {
        return RC_ERR_ARG;
    }

    static uint16_t oldAverage = 0;
    uint32_t average = 0;

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        average += buffer[i];
    }

    uint16_t newAverage = average/size;//simple_filter(oldAverage, (average/size));

    *AverageADC = newAverage;
    latestAverageADC = newAverage;

    if( latestAverageADC != oldAverage)
    {
        oldAverage = latestAverageADC;
        return RC_SUCCESS;
    }
    // TODO for test only return RC_ERR_UNKNOWN;
    return RC_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What values you expect? What voltages there are on the pin, do they match the readings?

Comment: I am talking about pin4 from image.

Comment: Pin number 4 is the reset pin, which can't be read with an ADC.

Comment: Sorry Pa4 is pin7. So pin7. Sorry,

Comment: PA4 is configured as DAC output. Why are you reading a DAC output pin with ADC? Nevertheless, if the voltage on the pin matches what the ADC reads, the problem is not the ADC, it is the voltage. So have you measured that the ADC readings match the voltage or not?

Comment: You should add your code. It can be that the conversion time is too short. It can be wrong reference voltage, it can be wrong settings of ADC bit conversion, etc..

Comment: Thank you. I add code. newAverage is my value.

Comment: I change Pa4 to ADC2_IN.

Comment: The code you posted has little relevance, as if it gets garbage values in, it gives you garbage values out. Have you validated what values go in to your function?

Comment: Post *all* your code; I don't see where you are configuring the ADC, nor where you are actually reading the ADC value. Also, don't try to average until you're getting values that "smell right". Start simple, build up complexity when the simple stuff works.